# In JIRA, how can I find every issue I have ever changed?

Tags: jira, jql

Sometimes, I edit many bugs with similar changes, and forget precisely which ones I touched. Or I edit a bug that was assigned to me and then that bug gets assigned to someone else, but I need to recall that bug report.

I know how to find issues in which I changed a *specific* field using [`CHANGED BY`](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiracoreserver073/advanced-searching-operators-reference-861257221.html#Advancedsearching-operatorsreference-CHANGEDCHANGED) in JIRA query language:

```
status CHANGED BY CurrentUser()
```

However, I don't know how to find issues where I changed *any* field or added any comment. How do I find these issues?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it is not supported with JQL yet (I may be wrong). But if you really need these issues, one alternative solution is to access the database and create your own query.